# Catching data from multiple checkboxes in a POST request

Tags: php, post, checkbox

Many thanks for checking this question. I have a simple email system on my website between users. Below is a section of code which is a foreach loop pulling out each email in a users inbox and displaying the subject and author etc. I have a delete checkbox to go with each one. I am struggling to see how I get catch the emails that have been selected for deletion in a POST request. I am thinking that it probably involves an array but not sure. All checked boxes have the same value of 'delete' so it should be easy enough, but I can't find a solution

```
 <!-- LOOPING THROUGH ALL THE RESPONSES TO THE GIVEN THREAD -->

    <?php foreach($messages as $message):?>
     < div class="message_strip">
       <table>      
       <tr>
        <td>
        <?php $id = $message->sender_id;?>        
        <img style="width:30px; margin:2px;" 
         src="../<?php echo grab_thread_thumbnail($message->sender_id); ?>"/>       
        </td>
       <td>                  
       <div>       
         <?php echo $message->style_email($message->message_id);?>        
        <div class="sender">
        <?php $user=User::find_by_id($message->sender_id);
        echo htmlentities($user->first_name);?>&nbspwrote on 
        <?php echo datetime_to_text($message->time); ?>
        </div>
       </td>
       <form action="message_folder.php" method="post">
       <td class="delete_checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" name="delete" value="delete">
       </td>
       </form>
       </tr>            
       </table>
       </div>
       </a>       
       <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap the checkbox input in the form tags.  Wrap your entire `foreach` in the form tags, and you'll need a submit button.

Assuming you want the `message_id`:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" name="delete[]" value="<?=$message->message_id ?>">
```

Then you will have an array of `message_ids` that were checked in `$_POST['delete']`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each checkbox a unique name, e.g. name='delete[$message->sender_id]', then iterate over the POST'ed array.